# Check if a node is a descendant of a scrollview in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to patch a library. It has the following piece of code:

```
const { scrollView } = this.state;
await this.state.currentStep.wrapper.measureLayout(
  findNodeHandle(scrollView), (x, y, w, h) => {
    // do something
  });
```

This works fine on Android. However, on iOS, if currentStep.wrapper (a React Element) is not inside the scrollview, the app crashes with the following error:

[image: Error]

This error cannot be catched. I need to check if the node is a descendant of the scrollview before doing measureLayout() to prevent the crash. Is it possible?

I'm using (react 17.0.2), and (react-native 0.66.3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
import { UIManager } from 'react-native';

UIManager.viewIsDescendantOf(
        A,
        B,
        async (isAncestor: boolean) => {
          // A, B have type node of element (specifically number) and you can also use findNodeHandle function to find it
          // isAncestor true shows that B is an ancestor of A
        },
);
```

Note: viewIsDescendantOf is a native function that is not defined in react-native typing, so you may have to cast the type to any to use it in typescript.